# How to determine which columns have no variability

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 50 columns and over 100,000 observations. I want to determine which columns have no variability (i.e., all rows contain the same value), print the names of the columns, and then remove those columns.

I tried using this code:

```
names(Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) != 0, df))
```

but I am not sure if it does what I want it to do. I think It lists the unique columns meaning no identical values?

Here is a sample from the data I am using:

```
135 24437208    1   2   1   Cardiology  ?   <30 8   8   None    No  No  Ch  No  No  Yes No  No  No  No  No  Down    No  Steady  None    Steady  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  77  33  6   0   0   0   [50-60) Female  Caucasian   ?   401.00  997.00  560.00
2   135 26264286    7   1   1   Surgery-Cardiovascular/Thoracic ?   >30 3   5   None    No  No  Ch  No  No  Yes No  No  No  No  No  Steady  No  No  None    Steady  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  31  14  1   0   1   0   [50-60) Female  Caucasian   ?   998.00  41.00   250.00
3   378 29758806    1   3   1   Surgery-Neuro   ?   NO  2   3   None    No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  None    No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  49  11  1   0   0   0   [50-60) Female  Caucasian   ?   722.00  305.00  250.00
4   729 189899286   7   1   3   InternalMedicine    MC  NO  4   9   >7  No  No  No  No  No  Yes No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  None    Steady  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  68  23  2   0   0   0   [80-90) Female  Caucasian   ?   820.00  493.00  880.00
5   774 64331490    7   1   1   InternalMedicine    ?   NO  3   9   >8  No  No  Ch  No  No  Yes No  No  No  No  No  Steady  No  No  None    Steady  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  46  20  0   0   0   0   [80-90) Female  Caucasian   ?   274.00  427.00  416.00
6   927 14824206    7   1   1   InternalMedicine    ?   NO  5   3   None    No  No  No  No  No  Yes No  Steady  No  No  No  No  No  No  None    No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  49  5   0   0   0   0   [30-40) Female  AfricanAmerican ?   590.00  220.00  250.00
7   1152    8380170 7   1   1   Hematology/Oncology ?   >30 6   2   None    No  No  No  No  No  Yes No  No  No  No  No  No  No  Steady  None    No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  43  13  2   0   1   0   [50-60) Female  AfricanAmerican ?   282.00  250.01  NA
8   1152    30180318    7   1   1   Hematology/Oncology ?   >30 6   6   None    No  No  Ch  No  No  Yes No  No  No  No  No  No  No  Down    None    No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  No  45  15  4   0   2   0   [50-60) Female  AfricanAmerican ?   282.00  794.00  250.00
9   1152    55533660    7
```

Comment: If everything is the same value with no variability, then you have `1` unique value, not `0`. So `Filter(function(x) length(unique(x)) != 1, df)` should do it.

Comment: So the results are the columns with no variability correct?

Comment: Other way around, the line of code I posted only keeps columns with variability from `df` - see `sapply(df, function(x) length(unique(x)) != 1 )` if you want to actually get `TRUE` and `FALSE` selections for your `df` columns.